# A fully clamped sinusoidal wave has its RMS multiplied by the square root of 3. Is my textbook mistaken?

Tags: rms, diode-clamp

A fully clamped sinusoidal wave has its RMS multiplied by the square root of 3: Vo = 1.73Vi

[image: Proof]

My textbook says that clamper circuits don't affect the Vpp and Vrms of an AC signal.

Obviously, Vpp didn't change, but Vrms must certainly change according to this calculation. Is my textbook mistaken? Does this magnification have any practical uses?

Comment: What textbook (and chapter) are you working from?

Comment: $$\sqrt{\frac1f\int_{_0}^\frac1f V_{_0}^2\left[1+\sin\left(\omega t\right)\right]^2}=\sqrt{3}\cdot\frac{V_{_0}}{\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{3}\cdot V_{_\text{RMS}}$$That all happens simply because the `1` adds to the \$\frac12\$ (constructed from the sine-squared integral term) to make \$\frac32\$. So it's pretty straight-forward. I admit I've been quite shocked at the poor quality of textbooks (and teachers) being used in the US to teach electronics -- at least, as I've experienced in working with one community college department here. So what's the textbook. (And I probably won't be shocked.)

Comment: The other obvious (and more usual way) is to just remember that for DC-offset sinusoids, \$V_{_\text{RMS}}=\sqrt{V_{_\text{DC}}^{\:2}+\frac12V_{_0}^2}\$. Since in this case \$V_{_\text{DC}}=V_{_0}\$ then \$V_{_\text{RMS}}=\sqrt{V_{_0}^{\:2}+\frac12V_{_0}^2}=V_{_0}\sqrt{\frac32}\$. Same result. Point I'm making is that it sounds as though the textbook may be wrong on part of what it said.

Comment: (is *clapping* a contraction of *clamping&clipping*?)

Comment: $$\overline{\text{V}}:=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\text{T}}\int\limits_0^\text{T}\left(\hat{\text{u}}_\text{dc}+\hat{\text{u}}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{\text{T}}\cdot t\right)\right)^2\space\text{d}t}=\displaystyle\sqrt{\hat{\text{u}}_\text{dc}^2+\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\text{u}}^2}{\displaystyle2}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a sine wave with a peak-to-peak value of 2P volts, its RMS value is the peak (which is P) divided by √2 or P/√2 and its DC value is 0. When the sine wave is clamped to 0 volts, its peak-to-peak value is still 2P but it is now has a DC value of P volts. Therefore, its RMS value is now given by √(DC^2 + RMS^2) or √(P^2 + (P/√2)^2) which reduces to √(P^2 + P^2/2) = √(3(P^2)/2) = √3(P/√2) = √3RMS value. So your textbook is correct. The extra value is supplied by the clamping circuit.

Comment: I think the questioner is worried about the textbook, writing, *"My textbook says that clamper circuits **don't affect** the Vpp and **Vrms** of an AC signal."* I think they know what the answer should be. The textbook appears to be **incorrect**, if it is being quoted correctly.